# Convert Grub entry to Grub2 entry?

Tags: grub2

So here's the thing.
I have two partition in my netbook (plus swap):

`/dev/sda4` with Ubuntu 10.4
`/dev/sda5` with Centos 5.5

I use Ubuntu obviously. Centos is there because I need to run some test on that distro. The problem is Centos uses Grub and Ubuntu uses Grub2.

This is `/boot/grub/menu.lst` from Centos:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,4)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz

    title CentOS (2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen)
            root (hd0,4)
            kernel /boot/xen.gz-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5
            module /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen ro root=LABEL=/1 rhgb quiet
            module /boot/initrd-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen.img
    title CentOS (2.6.18-194.el5xen)
            root (hd0,4)
            kernel /boot/xen.gz-2.6.18-194.el5
            module /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.el5xen ro root=LABEL=/1 rhgb quiet
            module /boot/initrd-2.6.18-194.el5xen.img
```

The `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from Ubuntu:

```
menuentry "CentOS release 5.5 (Final) (on /dev/sda5)" {
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,5)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 66daaf1a-53b0-4e12-96f3-db01d52e12d1
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen root=/dev/sda5
}
menuentry "CentOS release 5.5 (Final) (on /dev/sda5)" {
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,5)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 66daaf1a-53b0-4e12-96f3-db01d52e12d1
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.el5xen root=/dev/sda5
}
```

This was generated running `update-grub2` and `grub-install` under Ubuntu.
It's not working. It gives me something like *bad magic number*.

How can I convert the grub1 entry in a grub2 shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so since I was unable to find specific information on a proper conversion of grub1 for Centos5.5 that's what I did.

```
menuentry "CentOS release 5.5 (Final) (on /dev/sda5)" {
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,5)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 66daaf1a-53b0-4e12-96f3-db01d52e12d1
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

Basically I chainloaded grub1 loader inside grub2 loader.

Answer (score 1):

in [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) there are all information you need to know about grub