# Fedora login gone after Ubuntu updates on a dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, updates, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu does not put Fedora into GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171947/ubuntu-does-not-put-fedora-into-grub-menu)

After a software update for Ubuntu, my dual boot with Fedora will not show Fedora in the start menu. It just boots into Ubuntu and when I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and boot, it only has Ubuntu in the list.

I have tried the post about installing grub-customizer but when I run that, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer
```

I cannot find any other way to fix this problem. I am a complete newbie to Linux.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Note that we cannot help if the problem is Fedora-related, but IMHO this looks on-topic.

Comment: it is the 12.04 version. fedora was 17 and both are fresh installs. i installed Ubuntu first then Fedora. Fedora asked to shrink Ubuntu and after all install both showed on boot menu. then i booted into Ubuntu and done the updates and when it rebooted thats when Fedora was missing from the boot menu.

Comment: OK. We can probably help with that here.

Answer (score 0):

After mounting the Fedora partition in Ubuntu, you can see the `menu.lst` file of Fedora which will be located in `/boot/`. Convert the entry which says title Fedora to a [GRUB 2 entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11775/convert-grub-entry-to-grub2-entry) and include it in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the Ubuntu filesystem. Save and restart. You will get back your Fedora.

Note: you have to edit this file as super user, i.e. with

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: One should not use `sudo` with a graphical program due to possibilities of extraneous Xauthority files. Always use `gksudo` with a graphical program.

Comment: shouldn't a `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu pick it up and make this addition automatically? I guess it does. Do give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't.  I gave it a try.